# How to disable scrolling on body when finishing scrolling on a div?

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I have a TOC ( Table of content ) on the left of the website as :

```
#toc
position: fixed;
left: 0;
bottom: 0;
margin: 0;
overflow-y: auto !important;
overflow-x: auto !important;
```

I can scroll there normally, but when I finish scrolling vertically,the body starts to scroll instead. How do I disable the body from scrolling in this case only..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to prevent this behavior, you should add a container element inside your `<body>` and add the scrolling content inside it and make it scroll instead of `<body>`. In other words, `<body>`  shouldn't have scroll. If it has scroll browser will pick it up.

Comment: How do I prevent body from scrolling and make the container scrolling instead ?

Comment: @BilalHalayqa add `overflow:auto` with a `height`